# DDD: Instantiate Value objects inside Aggregate or pass it as parameter?

Tags: domain-driven-design, value-objects

When creating aggregates, should we create value objects inside aggregates, or we should pass already created value objects to ctor or factory.

```
 public Booking(DateTime arrivalDate, DateTime departureDate)
 {
      this.ArrivalAndDepartureinformation = new ArrivalAndDepartureInfo(arrivalDate, departureDate);
 }
```

or

```
 public Booking(ArrivalAndDepartureinformation arrivalAndDepartureInfo)
 {
            this.ArrivalAndDepartureinformation = arrivalAndDepartureInfo;
 }
```

Comment: The question is: How do you use those constructors and where do those constructor parameters come from?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Instantiate Value objects inside Aggregate or pass it as parameter?

- If we speak about passing parameters into constructor, it depends on how it is used. There might be some infrastructure limitations that can require usage of primitive types.
- If we speak about passing parameters into methods then Value Objects is 100% my choice.

In general, I'd say **it is better to pass value objects into your aggregates**.

Value Objects can:

- make language of you model more expressive
- bring type safety
- encapsulate validation rules
- own behavior

Comment: So input parameters which are sent to application service, are used to construct value objects which will be sent to aggregate factory or constctors

Comment: Yes. And you can get less parameters, more specific types for you parameters and more expressive language in your model.

Answer (score 6):

The general guideline I would recommend is this:

- Inside the domain model, use value objects as much as possible.
- Convert primitives into value objects at the boundary of the domain model (controllers, application services).

For example, instead of this:

```
public void Process(string oldEmail, string newEmail)
{
    Result<Email> oldEmailResult = Email.Create(oldEmail);
    Result<Email> newEmailResult = Email.Create(newEmail);

    if (oldEmailResult.Failure || newEmailResult.Failure)
        return;

    string oldEmailValue = oldEmailResult.Value;
    Customer customer = GetCustomerByEmail(oldEmailValue);
    customer.Email = newEmailResult.Value;
}
```

Do this:

```
public void Process(Email oldEmail, Email newEmail)
{
    Customer customer = GetCustomerByEmail(oldEmail);
    customer.Email = newEmail;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The domain model should speak domain, not implementation primitives.

Your application component normally owns the responsibility of taking raw data and expressing it in the model's language.